# Why is na.omit in R replacing everything with 0?

Tags: r

Goal: remove any rows that contain NA.

Problem: na.omit is just replacing it with 0.

I don't want zeros - I want the data point (row) removed completely.

I'm not sure if na.omit is picking up on a package I use for the rest of my script, but base::na.omit(dtemp) returns that na.omit doesn't exist in baseR. Am I missing something?

I've tried restarting R Studio but that didn't help.

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm slowly losing it over here...

```
dtempomit <- na.omit(dtemp)

dtempomit
     Dam  Rat Group    Sex Treatment LDB.Behaviour.Frequency
1    BK1 BN21   Con   Male       NCS                       9
2    BK2 BN22   Con   Male       NCS                       6
3    BK3 BN23   Con   Male       NCS                       5
4    BK4 BN24   Con   Male       NCS                       5
5    BK5 BN25   Con   Male       NCS                       6
6    BK7 BN26   Con   Male       NCS                       6
7    BK8 BN27   Con   Male       NCS                       7
8    BK6 BN28   Con   Male       NCS                       8
9   BK19 BN29   Con   Male       NCS                       6
10  BK20 BN30   Con   Male       NCS                       3
11   BK9 BN51   PNS   Male       NCS                       6
12  BK11 BN52   PNS   Male       NCS                       2
13  BK12 BN53   PNS   Male       NCS                       0
...

 dtempomit <- base::na.omit(dtemp)
Error in get(name, envir = ns, inherits = FALSE) : 
  object 'na.omit' not found
```

Comment: Your code doesn't do anything but throw an error - when R hits an error it means it can't execute that line of code. Nothing is being replaced by 0 by that line - that line isn't able to run.

Answer (score 1):

It should be from `stats` package and not from `base`

```
dtempomit <- stats::na.omit(dtemp)
```